# React can't null datetime-local input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using react together with react-semantic-ui and I'm having following input type:

```html
<Input 
onChange={e => this.onTextInputChange(e, 'date')}
value={this.state.searchQuery.date}
type='datetime-local'/>
```

`onTextInputChange` function sets input value as the state field and value of this input is bound to this field. Also, I have an additional button in my app which is responsible for clear form fields (by setting null on each state field).

```js
state = {
  searchQuery: {
     date: null
 }
}
```

Clear works pretty well for other fields, but the problem occurs when I touch `datetime-local` input. When I fill some part of the date I'm getting this message when I hit the clear button.

[image]

I'm able to clear this field only when I provide a full date. I know I can solve this issue by setting the value of this field to blank string `' '` during clear, but it isn't the best solution, because later I have to filter out those fields. I was even playing with react ref, but unfortunately I didn't achieve any positive result, what's more, blue cross which appears on hover clears the form. Any tips how can I handle it in a pretty way?

Edit #1:
`event.preventDefault` helped me to get rid of this validation message, but anyway input stays without cleared value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found the way to handle it.

I've made `Ref` in the constructor:

```
...
 dateRef: any;

  constructor(props: Readonly<Properties>) {
    super(props);

    this.dateRef = React.createRef();
  }
...
```

assigned ref to my input:

```
<Input
...
type='datetime-local'/
ref={this.dateRef}
...
/>
```

In clearForm method I set `''` on UI and null value in state.

```
  private clearForm = (event: React.FormEvent): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.date.current.inputRef.current.value = '';
    this.setState({searchQuery: EMPTY_SEARCH_QUERY});
  }
```

Also I'm preventing from search in case when input is invalid by accesing `this.dateRef.current.inputRef.current.validity.valid`

Maybe this solution isn't the best but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `this.state.searchQuery.date` to an empty string instead of null. In an input of type date, `value={null}` is not a valid as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). It is the only solution to this problem. If you specifically need null values you need to parse the empty string as null to avoid having to filter.

> Value: A DOMString representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty

Regarding the blue clear button, webkit has a pseudo-element `input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button` that allows you you style it after your needs. It is however pretty straightforward to implement a clear-button yourself as styling the button through CSS is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Am I able to access method which is called when I hit the blue button?

Comment: What I meant was that you can create a react component that fills the same purpose. You can style your own clear-button component but not the default one in all browsers as mentioned.